# Using Bayesian statistics in time series forecasting

Tags: time-series, data-mining, bayesian, kalman-filter

I would like to forecast demand count time series of taxi fleets at different locations on the map at different points in time. I.e. multivariate demand Time series forecasting.

Given hierarchinal demand time series. where the region level time series is the sum of district level time series at each point in time and district level time is the sum of city level time series at each point. sum of all the city level time series at each point in time should equal region level time series. There are also covariate time series (both numerical and categorical) associated with each city's demand time series. e.g. rainfall level, temperature, traffic level, taxi supply amount, date information like weekday or weekend, holiday information and Time invariant features like type of city. (e.g. industrial, CBD, residential etc. )

Note: The city level time series are quite sparse ( have many zeros).

How do I go about using a bayesian framework/statistics to model and predict the mutivariate  (city-wide) demand time series?

The reason for choosing the bayesian framework is to

1. estimate uncertainty in the prediction.
2. Build a strong prior sequentially over time which can capture the fundamental data distribution/patterns without being affected by noise in instantaneous data.
3. incorporate the various pieces of covariate information together to enhance prediction accuracy.

Here are my thoughts:

- Use summary statistics of covariate time series and response time series like ACF to compare similiarities between and try to explain causation.
- Try to improve dataset quality by (probably using bayesian a hierarchical model using partial pooling) to combine sparse and low quality (lowly correlated time series to response time series) covariates to model a better covariate.
- Use bayesian sequential learning to sequentially accumulate learned patterns over time into the prior distribution.

Could someone give me your thoughts and suggestions on how to go about doing this?
Thanks.

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/627420/247274)

Comment: @Dave what is wrong in asking from multiple sources? Why do you comment as duplicate? Your comment is unhelpful!

Comment: Can you write down the likelihood of your next observation given the previous one? If you can then do it for all the points in your times series, then combine it with the probability of your parameter prior - and you have yourself the non-normalized posterior. All you need then is some MCMC to sample from it. I would need to see the likelihood expression to be more specific